# Get values from YAML file with Java

Tags: java, yaml

I'm not that great in Java but want to improve my skills.
I'm working on a tracking app and want to store data in a YAML file.
So far, so good. The YAML file is written (manually) and now I want to read (and later write) the file.

I can't find any good tutorials that I can understand. There are some, but they are confusing or not help me at all. I've found SnakeYAML but there's also Jackson, etc.

Here's an example of my YAML file:

```yaml
--
telegramID: NULL
userID: NULL
firstName: NULL
lastName: NULL
eMailAddress: NULL@NULL.app
phoneNumber: NULL
birthdate: NULL
address:
    streetAddress: NULL
    city: NULL
    state: NULL
    postalCode: NULL
    country: NULL
2021-02-11:
    sleep:
        wokeUpAt: 10:00
        wentToBedAt: 00:30
    steps: 6425
    medication:
        22:45:
            what: NULL
            howMuch: 2
    supplements:
        12:10:
            what: Magnesium 500
    food:
        11:00:
            what: Bread
            howMuch: 4
        16:20:
            what: Bread
            howMuch: 4
        18:20:
            what: Burritos
            howMuch: 2
2021-02-12:
    sleep:
        wokeUpAt: 09:00
        wentToBedAt: 00:15
    steps: 384
    medication:
        12:05:
            what: NULL
            howMuch: 2
        20:00:
            what: Null
            howMuch: 2
    supplements:
        13:00:
            what: Magnesium
    food:
        10:00:
            what: Breat
            howMuch: 2
        14:55:
            what: Burritos
            howMuch: 2
        19:10:
            what: Burrito
            howMuch: 1
```

etc. etc. etc
I've changed personal data to NULL, It's not necessary to have it here.

All I want is to later be able to specify a date and to get back a list of values (time, what, etc.)
It would be nice to have it accessible via food.what, medication.howMuch, etc.
The problem here could be that the time is in here too. Maybe than an array like food.what[0], medication.howMuch[1], etc.? idk

Could you please help me with a good tutorial or code snippet? Any help is highly appreciated!

P.S. it doesn't have to be SnakeYAML, that's the first one I found for Java.

Comment: Is it important for you to use the YAML file here? It makes some issues with parsing dates as you use ```:``` separator there so it might cause an invalid read result in the code. I would recommend you to use JSON instead.

Comment: @Marcin YAML is absolutely fine with that, `:` is only a separator when succeeded by whitespace.

Comment: @Fachinformatiker I believe this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml) will help you.

Comment: This question seems off-topic as library recommendations tend to attract subjective answers. If you have a specific problem with either SnakeYAML or Jackson, edit the question to ask about that problem. Be aware that Jackson's API is primarily tailored towards JSON (and uses SnakeYAML under the hoods for YAML processing), so you will get more control when using SnakeYAML directly.